# Issue in printing PDF through UrlFetchApp in Apps Script: Gujarati (Shruti) fonts renders with extra line spacing and spaces

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

In Google Sheets, when we print a range as PDF using UrlFetchApp built in method of Apps Script, the Gujarati (Shruti) fonts occupies more space then the sheet; while we print the same range using their "Print" button or "Ctr + P", it prints the fonts with correct spaces.

I have observed that the english fonts are rendered perfectly in both the methods. But the Gujarati fonts have more line spacing and they occupies more size, when print PDF through UrlFetchApp.

Is there any option or any other method, that I can use their "Ctr + P" functionality through Apps Script?

Is there any other method so that I can render the Gujarati fonts in such a way that it occupies the less space like "Ctr + P" ?

**Example:** [See this Google Spread sheet(You are editor)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a_EOU9_JFpVIdtzqaRJROZQdmZz5azM3PLotUyPWZkY/edit?usp=sharing)

Steps:

1. Select the range "A1:A13" and click Print button or Ctr + P, select "Selected cells" to print.
2. Print the range through Extension > Print > Download range A1:A13. (Apps Script project and code is there in the Spread Sheet)
3. Compare both PDFs and sheet with each other.

Comment: Can you provide your sample code for this?

Comment: It is there in that spreadsheet as a document bound script. Open above link of Example > Go to Extensions Menu > Apps Script.

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION:**

I couldn't come up with a way to apply text wrapping to the PDF file that was generated, but I noticed that copying the file into a Google Doc and generating a download URL preserves table formatting even with the Gujarati (Shruti) fonts. Here is what I have cooked.

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createAddonMenu()
    // .addItem('Export all sheets', 'exportAsPDF')
    // .addItem('Export all sheets as separate files', 'exportAllSheetsAsSeparatePDFs')
    // .addItem('Export current sheet', 'exportCurrentSheetAsPDF')
    // .addItem('Export selected area', 'exportPartAsPDF')
    // .addItem('Export predefined area', 'exportNamedRangesAsPDF')
    .addItem('Download range A1:A13', 'downloadSpecificRangeAsPDF')
    .addToUi()
}

function downloadSpecificRangeAsPDF() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Print this using url and using default function");
  var specificRangeA1 = 'A2:A13';
  var range = sheet.getRange(specificRangeA1);
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var fontfamily = range.getFontFamilies().flat();
  var fontstyles = range.getFontStyles();
  var fontweight = range.getFontWeights();
  var fontsize = range.getFontSizes().flat();
  var fontcolor = range.getFontColorObjects().flat();
  var values = range.getValues();  
  var sheetName = ss.getName();
  
  var docId = DocumentApp.create(sheetName).getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var docUrl = doc.getUrl();
  console.log(docUrl);
  var fileName = doc.setName(sheetName);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var table = body.appendTable(values);

  console.log(fontstyles);

  for(let i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++){
    var style = {};
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = fontfamily[i]; 
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = fontsize[i]; 
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = fontcolor[i].asRgbColor().asHexString();
    style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = fontweight[i] == 'bold' ? true: false;
    console.log(style)
    table.getCell(i,0).setBackgroundColor(backgrounds[i]);

    if(style.FOREGROUND_COLOR != '#ff000000'){
    table.getRow(i).setAttributes(style);
    }

  }
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/" + docId + "/export" +
      "?format=pdf"

  downloadPDF(fileName, url, header = "Downloading: " + fileName)
  
}

function downloadPDF(fileName, url, header){
  
  fileName += '.pdf';
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
  });

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      '<a target ="_blank" download="' +
      fileName +
      '" href = "data:application/pdf;base64,' +
      Utilities.base64Encode(res.getContent()) +
      '">Click here</a> to download, if download did not start automatically' +
      ' \
  var a = document.querySelector("a"); \
  a.addEventListener("click",()=>{setTimeout(google.script.host.close,300)}); \
  a.click(); \
  '
  
    ).setHeight(50),
    header? header : 'Downloading PDF..'
  );

}
```

What this does is that it creates a Google Document, and then I changed the URL to download it into PDF using the Google Doc that was created.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However I am working with large documents, here is an example [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c3_MlE5gRESVRq2KUAjReVRMF5yeryG6/view?usp=sharing), this is small document as compared to other documents, while I generate different monthly reports, they are having 500 to 1000 pages.  Cons of using DocumentApp as I have observed: 1. We cannot handle the cell margins (they are large as compared to Sheets) 2. To identify page break inside a table of DocumentApp is not easy, especially when I want to carry forward the totals of each page)